# HTML: how to remove "None" from a drop-down list

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have several drop-down lists in HTML, populated by data from an Excel sheet, which often, have empty cells/columns, so my drop-down lists become full of None (placeholder).

```
Ex.: Option 1
     ========
     Doctors
     Nurses
     None
     Month
     None
```

I cannot have these "None" removed in the backend, so I need a frontend solution. Any ideas?

## My code:

```
<div class="center_charts_menu_1">
  <select name="select_label" id="select_label" class="custom-select select_label">
    <option value="['1']" id="0" selected disabled hidden>lengend</option>
    <option value="{{ column_a }}" id='{{ label_a }}'>{{ label_a }}</option>
    <option value="{{ column_b }}" id='{{ label_b }}'>{{ label_b }}</option>
    <option value="{{ column_c }}" id='{{ label_c }}'>{{ label_c }}</option>
    <option value="{{ column_d }}" id='{{ label_d }}'>{{ label_d }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: when you put <option> tag it will make a cell, so you have to work with that first. may I know why you cant use backend for that?are you using any javascript framework ?

Comment: @ZubaerHaque I use Python in the backend. The problem is that my frontend is mostly based on each selected option, so the whole code expects it to always exist. If I remove one of these labels or columns, for example, part of my frontend will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your options id seems to have the same names. So you can select all option-elements with the id="None" and remove it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('select > #None').forEach(e => e.remove());
```

```html
<select name="select_label" id="select_label" class="custom-select select_label">
  <option value="['1']" id="0" selected disabled hidden>lengend</option>
  <option value="{{ column_a }}" id='Doctors'>Doctors</option>
  <option value="{{ column_b }}" id='Nurses'>Nurses</option>
  <option value="{{ column_c }}" id='None'>None</option>
  <option value="{{ column_d }}" id='Month'>Month</option>
  <option value="{{ column_d }}" id='None'>None</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!